# Iterative dividing by specific row for grouped dplyr data in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tibble

I would like to iteratively divide each value by a specific row within each level of a grouping variable. Here is some example data:

```
library(tidyverse)

d <- structure(list(group = c("blue", "blue", "blue", "red", "red", 
                     "red", "yellow", "yellow", "yellow", "green", "green", "green"
), level = c("a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", 
         "b", "c"), value = c(1.666667, 1.333333, 1, 5, 4, 1, 6, 5, 1, 2.75, 2.25, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                    -12L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


d
 # A tibble: 12 x 3
   group  level value
   <chr>  <chr> <dbl>
 1 blue   a         5
 2 blue   b         4
 3 blue   c         3
 4 red    a        10
 5 red    b         8
 6 red    c         2
 7 yellow a         6
 8 yellow b         5
 9 yellow c         1
10 green  a        11
11 green  b         9
12 green  c         4
```

So, let's say that I'd want to divide each value found within each group by the *c* level. In this case, the result would look like this:

```
result
# A tibble: 12 x 3
   group  level value
   <chr>  <chr> <dbl>
 1 blue   a      1.67
 2 blue   b      1.33
 3 blue   c      1   
 4 red    a      5   
 5 red    b      4   
 6 red    c      1   
 7 yellow a      6   
 8 yellow b      5   
 9 yellow c      1   
10 green  a      2.75
11 green  b      2.25
12 green  c      1
```

Is there a way to do this using tidyverse functionality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the `level` is not duplicated within 'group', after grouping by 'group', extract the 'value' that corresponds to the 'c' level (`value[level == 'c']`) and use that to divide the 'value' column

```
library(dplyr)
d %>% 
   group_by(group) %>%
   mutate(value = value/value[level == 'c'])
# A tibble: 12 x 3
# Groups:   group [4]
#   group  level value
#   <chr>  <chr> <dbl>
# 1 blue   a      1.67
# 2 blue   b      1.33
# 3 blue   c      1   
# 4 red    a      5   
# 5 red    b      4   
# 6 red    c      1   
# 7 yellow a      6   
# 8 yellow b      5   
# 9 yellow c      1   
#10 green  a      2.75
#11 green  b      2.25
#12 green  c      1
```

Or if there are multiple 'c', then use `match` to get the index of first occurrence of 'c'

```
d %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(value = value/value[match('c', level)])
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
d$value <-  d$value/with(subset(d, level == 'c'), setNames(value, group)[d$group])
```

#### data

```
d <- structure(list(group = c("blue", "blue", "blue", "red", "red", 
"red", "yellow", "yellow", "yellow", "green", "green", "green"
), level = c("a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", 
"b", "c"), value = c(5, 4, 3, 10, 8, 2, 6, 5, 1, 11, 9, 4)), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: This works perfectly. I didn't realize that you could specify a level from another column within the index of a column. I will accept as soon as the delay runs out.